# A question regarding double integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

When is the following equality not true:

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\mathrm dy 
\ dx=\int_{y_1}^{y_2}[f(x_2,y)-f(x_1,y)] dy$$?
In other words, must there be any restrictions of $f(x,y)$ in order for the above to be true?

**EDIT:**
Following from the answer given below:
What about the case where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ diverges at some point of $[x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]$ but still $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}>0$ over $[x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction is that 
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\left|
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\mathrm dy\mathrm dx \right|<\infty
$$
i.e. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ if absolutely integrable on $[x_1,x_2]\times [y_1,y_2]$ then your move is justified. This is Fubini's theorem.

Alternatively, if you happen to know that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}>0$, you may also swap. This is Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: What about if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ diverges at some point of $[x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]$ but still $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}>0$ over $[x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]$?

Comment: But, if $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ diverges, then the first restriction that you pointed out(i.e. that the double integral does not diverge) is not satisfied, right?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand how $$\int_0^a \dfrac{1}{x^2} dx$$ where $a>0$ is not divergent. Maybe we are saying something different and I am not getting you?   Also, I understand what you are stating about Tonelli's theorem, but I can't conceptually understand why we can substitute the condition of the partial derivative not being divergent with the partial derivative being positive.

Comment: I can understand this if we have some Jacobian that, along with the integrand, can give a non-diverging integral. But, with a trivial Jacobian($=dx dy dz)$, I cannot see how. In the 1D example you have given, I can't see how that integral is not divergent

Comment: I will try to ask this a bit differently. Can you give an example of an integral with a diverging integrand that is not itself divergent?